# Access filesystem in Karma-Jasmine

Tags: jasmine, karma-jasmine, karma-runner

I have a bunch of HTML5 canvas tests in my library which I run via Karma and Jasmine. If I detect differences in my tests I show the canvas DOM elements with my generated image output and a diff on the browser page. But when I run my tests in Chrome Headless and/or on my CI environment I have no way of checking the test results in case they fail. And that's currently the issue I'm facing: when I run the tests with a UI, they are green, if I run them in Chrome Headless they fail but I have no chance of checking my visual output.

As solution I'd like to write my generated images to disk. On local tests I can then check this folder what happened an on CI I can publish the result images as artifacts. But here comes the point: Karma and Jasmine seem to have no proper mechanism in place for this task. Also I could not find any plugin tackling this challenge of properly accessing the local file-system from your tests.

A tricky aspect is also that I cannot use promise (async/await) operations at the place where I want to save files. I am within a Jasmine CustomMatcher which does not have promise support I could try rewriting my tests again to handle the error reporting to Jasmine.

My attempts so far:

1. I started with a custom Karma reporter listening to browser logs and potentially use this as channel to hand over the image bytes to Node for writing to disk. But this additional plugin registration messed with my overall Karma configuration. Karma and Rollup were not working anymore once I registered my custom reporter and I never found out if such large byte amounts can be even transferred via this channel.
2. Then I started with an API via `karma-express-http-server` where I "upload" the files to be saved. But I stopped half way as such a simple task seem to require again a bunch of libs and custom implementation to get a simple file upload running (karma-express-http-server, multer). Also I need to rely on synchronous Ajax calls here which is not really future proof.
3. The Native File System API heavily relies on Promises so I cannot use it.

There must be a simpler way of just writing a file as part of your tests to disk while when using Karma and Jasmine.